# What is elliptic genera?

Tags: string-theory, mathematical-physics, differential-geometry, topology

What is [elliptic genera](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Elliptic_genera) in physics? 
Reading many relevant papers, they just defined [elliptic genus](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/elliptic+genus) as sort of partition function. 
I try to find useful materials to explain it, but I couldn't find it. 
Can you give some intuition for this terminology in physical view?

Comment: It is a mathematical term. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_of_a_multiplicative_sequence The elliptic genus of a manifold  when its arguments are specialised gives the Euler characteristic and the Hirzebruch signature.

Comment: see the answers in http://www.physicsoverflow.org/23261/